# Problem playing parallel effects

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, effects

I could not play the parallel effect which is defined by the following code:

```
var parallel:Parallel=new Parallel();
var E1:WipeDown=new WipeDown();
var E2:WipeLeft=new WipeLeft();
parallel.addChild(E2);
parallel.addChild(E1);
parallel.duration=2000;
parallel.target=this;
parallel.play();
```

On playin the effect by calling effect() function only the effect E1 is getting played.
If the code was:

```
parallel.addChild(E1);
parallel.addChild(E2);
```

instead of:

```
parallel.addChild(E2);
parallel.addChild(E1);
```

then only the effect E2 is getting played..

To summurize only the top most child effect is getting played..

Can any one plese suggest a solution...

```
<code>
<mx:Parallel target="{this}" id="wipeDownLeft" duration="2000">
    <mx:WipeDown target="{this}" duration="2000"/>
    <mx:WipeLeft target="{this}" duration="2000"/>

</code>
```

If above code is not clear one can check with this application(copy the code and run)
`code`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" minWidth="1024" minHeight="768" xmlns:ns1="*">  
    <mx:Canvas id="C" creationComplete="{E.play()}" width="50%" height="50%" backgroundColor="#387C44">
   </mx:Canvas>
    <mx:Parallel id="E" duration="2000">
        <mx:WipeLeft duration="2000" target="{C}"/>
        <mx:WipeDown duration="2000" target="{C}"/>
    </mx:Parallel>  
    <mx:Button click="E.play([C])" x="{C.width+10}" y="{C.height+10}">
    </mx:Button>
</mx:Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try setting the target property for each of the child effects instead?
Probably wouldnt hurt to do this for duration either...

I have only used effects in mxml, and this it how ive always done it (same with the doc examples?) - in fact have even done the dual wipe you are trying here, but not in AS...

[Edit] - I cannot see your mxml unlessI go into edit mode, but i cannot submit edits - use the code tags on it...

but same again, specify target and duration for the children not the parallel...

Comment: I had tried with mxml too..
<mx:Parallel target="{this}" id="wipeDownLeft" duration="2000">
    <mx:WipeDown target="{this}" duration="2000"/>
    <mx:WipeLeft target="{this}" duration="2000"/>

Comment: But no changes to the result..
<mx:Parallel  id="wipeDownLeft" >
    <mx:WipeDown target="{this}" duration="2000"/>
    <mx:WipeLeft target="{this}" duration="2000"/>
    </mx:Parallel>

Comment: If not clear plese check this application code

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" minWidth="1024" minHeight="768" xmlns:ns1="*">  
    <mx:Canvas id="C" creationComplete="{E.play()}" width="50%" height="50%" backgroundColor="#387C44">
   </mx:Canvas>
    <mx:Parallel id="E" duration="2000">
     <mx:WipeLeft duration="2000" target="{C}"/>
     <mx:WipeDown duration="2000" target="{C}"/>
    </mx:Parallel> 
    <mx:Button click="E.play([C])" x="{C.width+10}" y="{C.height+10}">
    </mx:Button>
</mx:Application>

Answer (score 0):

I think, the reason that, WipeLeft and WipeDown are mutually exclusive effects. But must performed in parallel. if you replace a  to the , then it will be work. Or if you replace WipeLeft (or WipeDown) effect to some other effect, f.ex. , then it will be work too.